# How can we create getMyFormData function like getFormData in magento for mysession

Tags: magento-1.8

I need to Create Form for Register. I don,t want to use Customer Block..
I need To store customer form data ... So i used customer session...
Now I want create my session function ...

```
public function getFormData()
    {
        $data = $this->getData('form_data');
        if (is_null($data)) {
            $formData = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerFormData(true);
            $data = new Varien_Object();
            if ($formData) {
                $data->addData($formData);
                $data->setCustomerData(1);
            }
            if (isset($data['region_id'])) {
                $data['region_id'] = (int)$data['region_id'];
            }
            $this->setData('form_data', $data);
        }
        return $data;
    }
```

So i want to modify this code to  myFormData how ..this is possible for my custom Extention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to create a function for that. Just call one that does not exist but make sure it starts with `set`.
For example `setMyCutomData`. Then you will be able to retrieve the data you passed to is by calling `getMyCustomData`

Comment: I want to create like this Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')...to ..Mage::getSingleton('vendor/session').. for my extension..is this possible

Comment: You need to create a model called [Namespace]_[Module]_Model_Session that extends the abstract session. But I don't think you need it.

Comment: can i use Mage::getSingleton('customer/session') for storing vendor data

Comment: Sure you can. But if the vendor is not a customer you should use `core/session`. It's more "politically correct"